# Cypress How to store global constants in a file that can be used across all spec files?

Tags: variables, testing, global, cypress

I'm looking for a way to store global constants in a file that could be used across all my spec files. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you want to write to these global variables from a spec file?

Comment: @Ackroydd I want to be able to write my global variables in one file and reference that file for global variables across several spec files.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the `cypress.json` file that is in your project root like this:

```
{
    "env": {
        "your_var": "your_value"
    }
}
```

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html

Once you set some env variables, you can reference them from your specs like this: `Cypress.env('your_var');`

Comment: I have decided to create a cypress.env.json file with a single environment variable ```{
  "usernameField": "input[name=j_username]"
}``` and calling it in my spec file ```cy.get(Cypress.env('usernameField')).type('username')``` . When I run my spec file I'm getting a ```TypeError: Cannot read propety 'split' of undefined``` Any ideas?

Comment: I believe it is because the environment variables are strings. Is there a way to create an environment variable that is not a string so that it may be used as I explained in my example above?

Comment: You should test that cypress.env.json is actually being read. Where are you putting this file?

Comment: I had it in the root of the cypress folder. Although I was able to get it to work by utilizing the cypress.json instead of the cypress.env.json.

Comment: The docs are a bit vague on some details. Looking at the Github source, cypress.env.json is read in from the same location as cypress.json (which is the project root, not the cypress folder).

Answer (score 5):

The following link might help with an easy way to set and get from env variables.
https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env.html#Syntax

```html
describe('My First Test', function() {
  it('it set value to global variable', function() {
    Cypress.env('some_variable', "hello")
  })
  it('it get value to global variable', function() {
    expect(Cypress.env('some_variable')).to.equal('hello')
  })
})
```

Comment: Helpful link is great. But better to provide code and explanation of it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion i have added the sample code along with the link

Answer (score 4):

I like to create a constants file such as constants.js as an exportable constants object:

```
export const NAME = {
FIRST: 'John',
LAST: 'Smith',
};
```

and in my spec files import them: test.spec.js

```
import { NAME } from '../../support/constants';

describe('Landing page', () => {
  beforeEach(() => cy.login());

  cy.get(NAME.FIRST).assertion('verify the name');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Global variables - sounds like fixtures.

See [writefile - JSON - Write response data to a fixture file](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/writefile.html#JSON)

```js
cy.request('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then((response) => {
  cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/users.json', response.body)
})

// our fixture file is now generated and can be used
cy.fixture('users').then((users) => {
  expect(users[0].name).to.exist
})
```

Care to share why you want to do so?
Sounds like it may be interesting.

Comment: Hi, I'm making a test suite where I will have several .spec files doing different tests. I want to store all my variables in one file that will then be used in all my spec test files. Ie. so that I can change a URL in one spot and have the URL update across all my test files.

Comment: Ok, so technically they are not **variables**, they are **constants**.

Comment: I agree the question is vague. It should follow to [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Ackroydd My apologies. This is my first post on stackoverflow and I will be sure to consult the page you linked in your comment, in the future.

Comment: @RichardMatsen Yes, I apologize for that mixup.

Answer (score 2):

since cypress is js, it is possible to define const in on js file (my-const.js) as

```
export const ARE_YOU_SURE='Are you sure';
```

and use them in another file as

```
import * as constants from "../[proper path]/my-conste.js";
...
var s = constants.ARE_YOU_SURE + ' about this?'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use environment variables stored in either *cypress.json* or *cypress.env.json*.

cypress.json

```
{
  "env": {
    "myVar": "value..."
  }
}
```

cypress.env.json

```
{
  "myVar": "value..."
}
```

You can use your environment variable using *Cypress.env('myVar')*.

```
const myVar = Cypress.env('myVar')
```

You can review your environment variables in the Settings tab of the cypress runner.

[image: cypress runner Settings]